# PFFacebookUtils from ParseSDK throwing PFUserAuthenticationController authenticationProviderForAuthType

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm getting a `[PFUserAuthenticationController authenticationProviderForAuthType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error` when trying to use Parse's PFFacebookUtilsV4 in my IOS App

This is being thrown when I call the

```
PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
```

function

I'm trying to do the basic iOS link up between the Parse SDK and the Facebook SDK.

- For the FB SDK I'm using v4.6
- For the Parse SDK I'm using v1.8.5

I've set my iOS project according to Parse and FB tutorials.  Indeed running with Facebook Login Kit I can log in no problem so am assuming my FB App is set up properly.

The debug stack is showing it has something to with the PFUserAuthenicationController

```
0x000000010bd2658d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc73f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bc73b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MyApp                               0x000000010a595d30 +[PFFacebookUtils _authenticationProvider] + 160
    6   MyApp                               0x000000010a595d8d +[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions:] + 48
    7   MyApp                               0x000000010a58af89
```

I've checked, double checked and triple checked my framework bundles to ensure they are correct.

I've looked at my Search Paths and that is correct

I've tried both header file bridging but with V4 of the class that's not needed (this is written in Swift)

I'm pretty much out of ideas!  Please help

Comment: sorry should have added that I'm building for iOS9 and I've added the pList including the new NSAppTransportSecurity requirements!

Answer (score 1):

ParseFacebookUtilsV4 1.9.0 was just released. Seems to resolve this problem.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-iOS